# boost::shared_mutex issues in 1.50

Tags: c++, boost, deadlock, boost-thread, softlock

Hi Fellow Boost Enthusiasts

We have run into a problem with shared_mutex and have been digging into the boost source.
We can't tell if this is a deadlock case, or we are just not understanding the shared
mutex implementation for reader/writer locks.

Application :

We have a map `map< Ptr*, data>` that needs to be created and queried by multiple threads.
However, *most* of the `Ptr*` values are common, so there is a fast warmup followed by
what we believe is a pattern of almost no insertions into the map. So we thought to use
a reader/writer pattern to control access to the map, like this

```
boost::mutex& lock_;
bool found = false;
{
  shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> slock(lock_);
  (search the map to see if you have key)
  if (keyFound) {
       found = true; 
  }
}
if (!found) {
   upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> ulock(lock_);
   (search the map again to see if the key has been inserted)
   if (key still found) {
     upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> wlock(ulock);
     insert into the map & do whatever
  }
}
```

The original shared_lock should be destroyed when the block goes out of scope,
making the upgrade_lock the only lock if the original shared_lock does not succeed.

Observations:

All our threads are stuck for days in

`_lll_lock_wait or pthread_mutex_lock`

Upon digging into the boost::shared_mutex implementation, we find that there is 
a single common "state_changed" lock inside the mutex, and in order for either the
shared_lock or unique_lock to succeed, it needs to acquire the common state_changed lock
for both lock construction and destruction. It seems that the unique_lock will go into
a state where it *may* release the scoped_lock on state_changed, but we cannot tell.
Either way, we cannot tell why the threads basically lock up for long periods of time
with sporadic progress - it's not quite a deadlock but something close.

Any help appreciated.

Sam Appleton

Comment: Take look at the [change log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html), in particular at issue #7755. Could it be the issue you encounter?

Comment: @IgorR. strange as it sounds, I'd rate that as an answer. It does answer the question, which is specifically "what's going on here". And the Q&A has a lot of community merit.

Comment: @sehe Done. (Actually, I meant to wait and see whether it actually solves the problem, but on second thought, an answer doesn't have to be correct :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Take look at `Boost.Thread` [change log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html), in particular at issue #7755 "Thread: deadlock with shared_mutex on Windows", which was fixed in 1.54. It might be the issue you encounter.

By the way, a lot of `Boost.Thread` bugs have been fixed since 1.50, so it's worth upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: This holds pretty high plausibility. I'd say the OP at least needs to test with the (patch from the) 1.54 version to see whether it removes the issue!

Comment: Thanks - we will attempt using 1.57 to see if issue is resolved.